# how to do a a dql, that fetch r_object_id and lifecycle statye of document

Tags: documentum

I need a dql, that fetch r_object_id and lifecycle statye of document

something like below :

select d.r_object_id, p.state_name from dm+document d, dm_policy p where object_name ='text.docx'  and ....
I am unable articulste exact where clause. Experts please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is DQL for something you would like:

```
SELECT r_policy_id, r_current_state, r_resume_state
FROM dm_document
WHERE object_name like 'LoanApp_%'
```

from https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/documentum-65-content/9781849680226/ch13s08.html

Of course, adjust WHERE clause to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for response, but r_current_state comes like 0,1,2,3.. This way , we cannot know the state name. Because of that I do not want r_current_state . dm_policy.state_name.Can you please help me this